# Highcharts issues with date

Tags: highcharts

I have a spline chart where in I am trying to achieve passrate starting today going 30 days back. Basically trying to see growth over period of last 30 days.

However I am seeing the dates mesing up in the x axis and they are going to october /months are added by 1 which means 26th Sep some how shown as 26th OCT.

Here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mn6sB/1/

Here is the code for the high chart -

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chartContainer',
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Pass rate statistics'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Pass count per'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
                    month: '%e %b',
                    year: '%b'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'PassCount'
                },
                min: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                         return '<b>'+ this.series.name +
                            '</b><br/> Date: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b',this.x)+
                                '</b><br/> Pass Count: '+ this.y;
                }
            },

            series: [{name: 'development', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,8,27),10],[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),5],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),12],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),12],[Date.UTC(2013,8,31),7],[Date.UTC(2013,9,2),13],[Date.UTC(2013,9,3),22],[Date.UTC(2013,9,4),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,5),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),7],[Date.UTC(2013,9,10),16],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),20],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),11],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),25],[Date.UTC(2013,9,14),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),11],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),16],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),12],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),22],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),10],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,22),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),40],[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),14],[Date.UTC(2013,9,26),6],]},{name: 'topbr', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),2],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,31),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,2),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,3),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,4),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,5),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,6),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,8),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,10),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,14),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,22),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,26),1],]},{name: 'xxsomething', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),10],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),1],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,6),10],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,8),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,14),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),42],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),42],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),41],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),16],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),4],[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),45],[Date.UTC(2013,9,26),2],]},{name: 'xxabcxos', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,6),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),1],]},{name: 'xxpqrs', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),2],[Date.UTC(2013,8,29),2],[Date.UTC(2013,8,30),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,2),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,3),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,4),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,7),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,8),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,9),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,10),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,11),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,12),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,16),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,17),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,18),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,19),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,20),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),2],[Date.UTC(2013,9,22),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,23),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,25),1],]},{name: 'xxsomething_th', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,1),3],[Date.UTC(2013,9,24),4],]},{name: 'xxpqrs_dev', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,13),1],[Date.UTC(2013,9,21),1],]},{name: 'xxrel', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,9,15),1],]},{name: 'xxfun', data:[[Date.UTC(2013,8,28),2],[Date.UTC(2013,9,5),1],]},]
        });
    });
```

Comment: So you are saying the chart should go from Aug.26 to Sep.26?

Comment: If so, when using Date, months are indexed from 0 not 1. So instead of using the natural '8' for August, you need to use '7'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Month start with 0, not 1 when using Date.

From a js console:

```
new Date( Date.UTC(2013,1,27) )
Tue Feb 26 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

new Date( Date.UTC(2013,0,27) )
Sat Jan 26 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```